# Code takes too long to run when looping through a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
signal = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 0],
                [-1, -1, -1],
                [1, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 1],
                [0, -1, 1],
                [-1, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0]],columns=['TKV','SWP','BWN'],index=date_index)

`
remove_duplicate(df,lookahead_days):
    df = df.copy()
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
    for i in range(0, signal.shape[0], lookahead_days-1):
        date_range = df.index[i:i+lookahead_days]
        for col in df.columns:
            duplicates = df[col][date_range].duplicated(keep="first")
            duplicates_index = df[col][date_range][duplicates].index
            df.loc[duplicates_index, col] = 0
    df.index = df.index.date
    return df`
```

my objective is to loop through the signal dataframe within a window of days(loookahead_days) and check if duplicates exist, and turn the latter ones to zero, keeping only the first one.

I have done that with the function above, the problem now is it takes too long to run, when i pass it through  the real dataframe with shape of about 1000X500.

I'm wondering if there's a better way that i should have done this.

Comment: Pandas has a [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method that will do what you need and be quick.

Answer (score 0):

***Setup***:

```
from pandas import Timestamp
signal = pd.DataFrame({'TKV': {Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-02 00:00:00'): -1, Timestamp('2018-01-03 00:00:00'): 1, Timestamp('2018-01-04 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-05 00:00:00'): 1, Timestamp('2018-01-06 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-07 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-08 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-09 00:00:00'): -1, Timestamp('2018-01-10 00:00:00'): 0}, 'SWP': {Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-02 00:00:00'): -1, Timestamp('2018-01-03 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-04 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-05 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-06 00:00:00'): 1, Timestamp('2018-01-07 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-08 00:00:00'): -1, Timestamp('2018-01-09 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-10 00:00:00'): 0}, 'BWN': {Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-02 00:00:00'): -1, Timestamp('2018-01-03 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-04 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-05 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-06 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-07 00:00:00'): 1, Timestamp('2018-01-08 00:00:00'): 1, Timestamp('2018-01-09 00:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-10 00:00:00'): 0}})
```

You can use **`drop_duplicates`** here, the tricky thing is that you need to create a column that will *never* result in duplicates outside of each `n`-day period (Or whatever time grouping you decide on).  Let's say that you want to drop duplicates if they appear within a 5 day period, we need to create a column that is duplicated for each of these periods, that we can use as a key to `drop_duplicates`:

```
s = (signal.reset_index()
        .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5d', key='index'))
        ['index'].transform('first')
    )

0   2018-01-01
1   2018-01-01
2   2018-01-01
3   2018-01-01
4   2018-01-01
5   2018-01-06
6   2018-01-06
7   2018-01-06
8   2018-01-06
9   2018-01-06
Name: index, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

This gives us a column that will always be the same for each 5-day period, but can be used to distinguish between *other* columns when checking for duplicates.  Now all we have to do is drop duplicates based off of our "flag" column, and the other columns we are checking for:

```
signal.assign(flag=s.values).drop_duplicates(['flag', 'TKV', 'SWP', 'BWN']).drop('flag', 1)

            TKV  SWP  BWN
2018-01-01    0    0    0
2018-01-02   -1   -1   -1
2018-01-03    1    0    0
2018-01-06    0    1    0
2018-01-07    0    0    1
2018-01-08    0   -1    1
2018-01-09   -1    0    0
2018-01-10    0    0    0
```

If instead of dropping duplicates, you'd like to simply replace them with `0`, you can make use of **`duplicated`** here.

```
tmp = signal.assign(flag=s.values)
tmp[tmp.duplicated()] = 0
tmp = tmp.drop('flag', 1)

            TKV  SWP  BWN
2018-01-01    0    0    0
2018-01-02   -1   -1   -1
2018-01-03    1    0    0
2018-01-04    0    0    0
2018-01-05    0    0    0
2018-01-06    0    1    0
2018-01-07    0    0    1
2018-01-08    0   -1    1
2018-01-09   -1    0    0
2018-01-10    0    0    0
```

This results in the last two entries from the first group getting dropped, as they were duplicated within that period, but *not* rows in the second group, even if they appeared in the first.

This should be *much* more performant than your option:

```
signal = pd.concat([signal]*2000)
signal = signal.reset_index(drop=True).set_index(pd.date_range(start='1995-01-01', periods=20000))

In [445]: %%timeit
     ...: s = (signal.reset_index().groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5d', key='index'))['index'].transform('first'))
     ...: signal.assign(flag=s.values).drop_duplicates(['flag', 'TKV', 'SWP', 'BWN']).drop('flag', 1)
     ...:
9.5 ms ± 277 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [482]: %%timeit
     ...: s = (signal.reset_index().groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5d', key='index'))['index'].transform('first'))
     ...: tmp = signal.assign(flag=s.values)
     ...: tmp[tmp.duplicated()] = 0
     ...: tmp = tmp.drop('flag', 1)
56.4 ms ± 205 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```